# Flex: Getting a variable from your regular component to an inline item renderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I am trying to turn labels red when they can no longer be added to a list because of size requirements. The renderer works but Flex creates a separate component. I can't think of any good way to get that value to the new component. Any ideas?

`<mx:List... >`

```
 <mx:itemRenderer>          
      <mx:Component>
         <comp:SetSizeLabel numIps="{data.numInSet}" remaining= "{remaining}"/>
      </mx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the outerDocument keyword to access the scope outside of the inline component. Look at [Example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mxml/component.html)